# Use of any server database for google assistant actions

Tags: database, google-assistant-sdk

I am using google assistant for creating my own actions and i am new to it. I want to use my own database and save user response to database.Can anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, Gautam! Your exact fulfillment code will vary depending on which database and cloud environment you choose. In my case, I built [an action](https://github.com/maaaaaaaax/bathroom-stall-Google-Assistant/) for the Google Assistant that creates an entry in a GCP [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/) NoSQL database.

This sample code creates an entry in my database:

```
app.intent('write to the wall', (conv) => {
    console.log(conv);
    console.log(conv.input.raw);
    var userReply = conv.input.raw;

    function writeToDb(userReply){

        const dialogflowAgentRef = db.collection('dialogflow').doc('agent');

        return db.runTransaction(t => {
          t.set(dialogflowAgentRef, {entry: userReply});
          conv.ask('The wall now reads, ' + userReply + '\n\n');
          conv.close("Thanks for visiting!");
          return Promise.resolve('Write complete');
        }).then(doc => {
          console.log(`Wrote "${userReply}" to the Firestore database.`);
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(`Error writing to Firestore: ${err}`);
        //   console.log(`Failed to write "${userReply}" to the Firestore database.`);
        });
    }

    return writeToDb(userReply);

});
```

Your database `create` function might look slightly different, but hopefully that helps you get started... provided you choose to use the tech stack introduced in [Actions on Google's codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/): Node.js, Dialogflow, and Firebase